# constructor lists in c++

Tags: c++, constructor

So basically, I have a class called vertex2. It is a class I am making for using OpenGL easier (for me). So I made a constructor. It took in a float list. But here's the problem. I tried to make a variable that was a list of floats; it was `float list[] = {1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0}` And i assigned a vertex2 and it worked. But I tried pasting that: `{1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0}` in the initialization, but it didn't work.

```
struct vertex2
{
    vertex2(float *vertices);
private:
    float *m_vertices;
public:
    float *ConvertToFloatArray();
};

static game::data::vertex2 vertices = { -0.5f, -0.5f,
    0.5f, -0.5f,
    0.5f, 0.5f,
    -0.5f, 0.5f };
```

But if I do this:

```
static float verts[] = { -0.5f, -0.5f,
    0.5f, -0.5f,
    0.5f, 0.5f,
    -0.5f, 0.5f };

static game::data::vertex2 vertices = verts;
```

it somehow works.

Comment: Also, I can't see your constructor, but I hope you're copying the array when you make the vertex instance. Because if not, then you're just borrowing it and will be hitting UB pretty quickly if the array goes out of scope.

Comment: The only way this can work is if `vertex2` knows ahead of time how many floats it's going to receive, and in that case there's no point to `m_vertices` being a pointer. It can be a plain old array and save a lot of trouble.

Answer (score 3):

When you're doing:

```
struct vertex2
{
    vertex2(float *vertices);
private:
    float *m_vertices;
public:
    float *ConvertToFloatArray();
};
static float verts[] = { -0.5f, -0.5f,
    0.5f, -0.5f,
    0.5f, 0.5f,
    -0.5f, 0.5f };

static game::data::vertex2 vertices = verts;
```

You are declaring a static variable with the vertexes and passing a pointer to it on the constructor and (**my guess, because you didn't included the complete code**) saving **the pointer** in your object. If someone modifies vertices, the vertices on the class will get modified (and likewise, if you modify your vertex on the class, it will modify vertices variable).

But when you do:

```
static game::data::vertex2 vertices = { -0.5f, -0.5f,
    0.5f, -0.5f,
    0.5f, 0.5f,
    -0.5f, 0.5f };
```

You're passing a list of floats, not a pointer.

Instead, i'll suggest you to play with this: https://ideone.com/GVvL8y

```
#include <array>

class vertex2 // use class whenever possible, not struct
{
public:
    static const int NUM_VERTICES= 6;

public:
    // Now you can only init it with a reference to a 6 float array
    // If you use float* you'll never know how many floats are there
    constexpr vertex2(float (&v)[NUM_VERTICES])
    : vertices{v[0], v[1], v[2], v[3], v[4], v[5]}
    {
    }

    // Will take a list of numbers; if there's more than 6
    // will ignore them. If there's less than 6, will complete
    // with 0
    constexpr vertex2(std::initializer_list<float> list)
    {
        int i= 0;
        for (auto f= list.begin(); i < 6 && f != list.end(); ++f) {
            vertices[i++]= *f;
        }
        while (i < NUM_VERTICES) {
            vertices[i++]= 0;
        }
    }

    constexpr vertex2() = default;
    constexpr vertex2(vertex2&&) = default;
    constexpr vertex2(const vertex2&) = default;

    float* ConvertToFloatArray() const;

    // Just for debugging
    friend std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream& stream, const vertex2& v)
    {
        stream << '{' << v.vertices[0];
        for (int i= 1; i < vertex2::NUM_VERTICES; i++) {
            stream << ',' << v.vertices[i];
        }
        return stream << '}';
    }

private:
    std::array<float, NUM_VERTICES> vertices{};
};
```

Answer (score -2):

Make like this

```
vertex2 vertices{(float []){-0.5f, -0.5f,
        0.5f, -0.5f,
        0.5f, 0.5f,
        -0.5f, 0.5f }};
```

Compiler try to use initializer_list as default, you should clearly indicate this as array

Comment: M.R. Needs to add an initializer list constructor to his class. See https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/initializer_list

Comment: It’s not  necessary

Comment: Then the floats will fall out of scope immediately, then using them at all will be UB.

Comment: I agree with you